# Cant find Sync link and compare button on bitbucket new interface

Tags: bitbucket

New user interface of bitbucket make me a little confuse. I just want to sync my repo from the parent repo. but I cant see any link of sync and compare button.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution. It's true that bitbucket no longer provide sync link when there is any update from parent repo (master branch). So the remaining option is only by comparing. We can access the compare menu by **choosing repo -> click plus button (on right side upper of the page) -> click Compare branches or tags**.